# PgfPlots: Scale X-Axis Non-linearly

Tags: pgfplots, scaling

I want to scale x-axis in a non-linear way. That is, for example, I want to have ticks 1,2,45,100,400 with equal distance between each of them. The scale between 1 and 2 , 2 and 45, etc.,  should be linear. I have searched internet extensively but couldn't find a clue.

Comment: This may sound like  a silly question, but will you have data points only at the ticks, or can there be datapoints for e.g. x=300 in your example?

Comment: @Bronsteinx you can use `xtick` and `ytick` options for `axis` environment. Look pgfplots guide.

Comment: @Torbjørn T., there will be other data points.

Comment: @juanuni, are you sure it works ? I think xtick will not change scale of the axis, but it will only put ticks at specified points. I will try however.

Comment: No, @juanuni's suggestion will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it probably is possible to do this in LaTeX alone, I'm lazy, and use Python with Numpy to create new x-values. This is assuming you have a data file with two columns of numbers, for `x` and `y`. I've added comments in the Python code, ask if anything is unclear.

```python
# I'm using Python 3, but I think this line will make it work with Python 2.x
from __future__ import division
# numpy for number juggling, sys to get arguments from command line
import numpy as np
import sys

# read the two columns from the specified file into x and y
x,y = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1],unpack=True)

# read tick locations from second argument and convert from str to float
ticks = sys.argv[2]
ticks = [float(i) for i in ticks.split(',')]


# in the case that the data are outside the specified tick locations,
# add a new tick for the smallest and/or largest x-value
if x[0] < ticks[0]:
    ticks = [x[0]] + ticks
if x[-1] > ticks[-1]:
    ticks = ticks + [x[-1]]

# make a new x-vector including tick locations, and interpolate y-values to tick locs
newx = np.unique((np.concatenate((x,ticks))))
newy = np.interp(newx,x,y)

# set up array for new x-values
weirdx = np.empty_like(newx)

for i in range(len(ticks)-1):
    # find all x-values that are between two adjacent ticks
    I = np.where( (ticks[i] <= newx) & (newx <= ticks[i+1]) )[0]
    if len(I) > 0:
        # Algorithm:
        #   take x values in range and subtract the first value (at first tick), so they start at 0
        #   divide by the last value (at last tick), so values run from 0 to 1
        #   add i, where i is the number of the first tick (counting from 0)
        subx = newx[I]
        subx -= subx[0]
        subx /= subx[-1]
        subx += i
        weirdx[I] = subx

# if the ticks are outside the data range, remove the x and y values at the first/last ticks
if x[-1] < ticks[-1]:
    weirdx = np.delete(weirdx, -1)
    newy = np.delete(newy,-1)
if x[0] > ticks[0]:
    weirdx = np.delete(weirdx, 0)
    newy = np.delete(newy,0)

# save new data file, and file with tick labels
np.savetxt('newdata.dat',np.hstack(( weirdx[:,np.newaxis], newy[:,np.newaxis] )), '%.8f')
np.savetxt('ticks.dat', ticks, '%u')
```

Save the script in the same folder as your data file and run

```
python ticks.py data.dat 1,2,45,200,450
```

where `ticks.py` is the name of the script file, `data.dat` is the name of the data file, and `1,2,...` is the list of tick locations. Note that you cannot have spaces in the tick list.

As a test I generated some numbers for a straight line `y = 2x`, for x between 0 and 495. The output and LaTeX code is below. Note that the locations of the ticks must be specified manually.

[image]

```tex
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotstableread{newdata.dat}\data
\pgfplotstableread{ticks.dat}\ticky
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xticklabels from table={\ticky}{[index]0},
  xtick={0,...,6},
  grid]
\addplot [black] table[x index=0,y index=1] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```